# помогите с архитектурой ios-приложения(MVP)

Tags: ios, swift, mvp, solid

Архитектура MVP.

Делаю приложение, которое позволяет пройти авторизацию через инстаграм, а затем отобразить некоторую информацию с вашего аккаунта.

я так понимаю, что у меня должна быть одна модель Profile(профиль страницы в инстагрме).

получается, что у меня будет один презентер к ней и один класс `ProfileService` для загрузки данных.

то есть 
`struct Profile`,

`protocol ProfileViewDelegate`

```swift
class ProfilePresenter {
         var pc: ProfileService
         var pfd: ProfileViewDelegate
}
```

`class ProfileService`

У меня уже есть два экрана: Авторизации и отображения профиля. Допустим у меня еще буду несколько экранов, например, для отображения списка подписчиков. Нужно ли мне для него тоже отдельно делать презентеры и тд? Нужно ли делать презентер для каждого экрана, для экрана авторизации и тд?

Если я неправильно понял, можете подсказать примерную структуру классов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите в профиле отображать изображения, то вам так же потребуется модель `Post`. 
Протокол для вью(`ProfileViewDelegate`) делать лучше так:

```swift
protocol ProfileViewDelegate: class
```

И в Presenter сделать `weak var pfd: ProfileViewDelegate`.

Так же нужно сделать протокол для Presenter. Например `ProfileOutput` в котором будут находится переменные и методы, которые вы хотите сделать. И во `view` указать не сам класс презентера, а протокол, от которого он наследуется.

То есть во view надо сделать примерно так:

```swift
class ProfileView: ProfileViewDelegate {
   var presenter: ProfileOutput! 
}
```

В данном случае можно поставить "!", так как он обязательно должен быть.

Для каждого контроллера должен быть свой презентр и надо разбивать приложение на модули.

Так же для каждого модуля должен быть Assembly/Builder(в разных командах его называют по разному) класс. Он может быть один на весь проект или под каждый модуль отдельно. Так как мы и в presenter, и во view завязываемся на протоколах, то надо сделать инъекцию зависимостей(Dependency injection). То есть сущности должны собираться из вне. Выглядеть он должен примерно так:

```swift
class ProfileAssembly {
  class func configureModule() -> ProfileViewController {
    let view = ProfileViewController() 
    let presenter = ProfilePresenter() 
    view.presenter = presenter 
    presenter.view = view 

    return view 
  }
}
```

Если вы хотите чтобы был один билдер на все приложение, то просто создаете для каждого модуля свой метод, например `configureProfileModule`, `configureFollowersModule`() и т.д.

Структура проекта должна быть примерно такой:

```
| 
| ProfileModule 
   |
   | Presentr
      |
      | ProfilePresenter 
   |
   | View 
      | 
      | ProfileViewController
   |
   | ProfileAssembly
|
|
| Model 
   | 
   | Profile 
|
| Services 
   |
   | NetworkService
```

Модель обычно выносится в отдельную директорию в папке проекта, так как она скорее всего будет использоваться по всему приложению. Если же она будет использоваться только в рамках модуля, то можно ее поместить в директорию модуля

Answer (score 0):

Суть архитектуры MVP в том, что презентер (P) управляет отображением контента (M) на вью (V). Т.е. да, для всех экранов нужен свой презентер.

Вот хорошая статья на тему архитектур:

https://habr.com/ru/company/badoo/blog/281162/